# How to creaate spring0boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, project

how are you?
I have problems to create a  spring-boot project. si create  it, i have an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYKxy.png)

[image]

i don't know can be a problem.
please,help  me to solve it.
thanks!!!

Comment: There’s no way to tell from this what the problem is. Maybe you just need to update your maven dependencies (right click on project folder in eclipse, choose maven,  dialogue pick project to update and click checkbox saying force update)

Comment: i do it but no changing. i don't know what to do again.

Comment: Does building with maven from the command line work? If so check how maven is set up in eclipse preferences.

Comment: but do you know how to integrate spring-boot with netbeans??

Comment: how to build with command line?

Comment: cd to the directory with the Pom.xml. Enter ‘mvn -U clean compile’.

Comment: Additionally, can you check whether an error is visible (any red symbol) in your pom.xml? Or try clean building your project. You can also check for right click your project- properties- Java Build Path- see if any error is visible.

Comment: ok. i'll do  your tips.thanks

Comment: What *is* the error? The exclamation mark means that there is a build path error but that could have many source. Maybe your network connection is not working, so that the dependencies couldn't be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Spring-boot application in many way .

1 using spring-io website 
2 using spring-boot cli
3 using maven project

- Create a maven project
- added spring-boot-starter-parent dependency in your  pom file. If you want to create a web application then add spring-boot-starter-web dependency in your pom
- added @SpringbBootApplication annotations on Application class
- inside main method called Application.run (yourClassName.clss,args) it's bootstrap your application .
- added Application.properties file inside the resource folder.